# Custom sort the notebooks in Evernote

Tags: evernote

The notebooks in Evernote seem to be arranged in alphabetical order. Is there any way to arrange the notebooks in another order, or maybe custom sort/arrange the notebooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As workaround you can prefix the notebook names with non-alphabetic characters to control the sort order. For example I prefix my notebooks with zero to three underscore characters ("_") to sort the notebooks in four groups, as so

- _Notebook1
- _Notebook2
- _Notebook3
- __Notebook1
- __Notebook2
- __Notebook3
- ___Notebook1
- ___Notebook2
- ___Notebook3
- Notebook1
- Notebook2
- Notebook3

You can use any other renaming scheme you find appropriate in your case, for example, simply prefix the notebooks by numbers ("1_", "2_", "3_", and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Notebooks can only be sorted (in the mobile app, it's the button to the left of the magnifying glass) by:

1. Title
2. Note count
3. User

Maybe you can request for custom sorting from Evernote.